# Probability - Discrete Maths

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

> Donal, Joy and Padraig run a dental practice in collaboration. The
>   following table shows the percentage of llings that they carry out,
>   and the percentage of those llings that they each carried out that
>   later on turn out to be faulty:
>
> Donal completed 32% of fillings and 5% of these were faulty. Joy
>   completed 41% of fillings and 2% of these were faulty. Padraig
>   completed 27% of fillings and 7% of these were faulty.
>
> Let D denote the event that Donal did the filling, J that Joy did the filling and P that Padraig did the filling. Compute P(D), P(F|J), P(F) AND P(P|F).
>   Blockquote

If someone could help me out with this question, it would be great. Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you include your attempts please?

Comment: What does the event $F$ mean?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the text in the question, I'll assume that the event $F$ is that the filling turns out to be "faulty".

If that is the case, then here are a few hints to get you started.

**(1)** For $P(D)$ we want the probability that Donald did the filling. In this context, another way of asking this question is *what percent of the fillings were done by Donald?*

**(2)** For $P(F|J)$ we want the probability that a filling is faulty given that it was done by Joy. Here we only want to focus on fillings done by Joy, so we ignore any info about Donald and Padraig. Then, *what percent of Joy's fillings turn out to be faulty?*

**(3)** For $P(F)$ we want the probability that a filling turns out to be faulty. Essentially we want to add up the following probabilities:

$$P(Faulty) = P(\text{Faulty and done by Donald}) + P(\text{Faulty and done by Joy}) + P(\text{Faulty and done by Padraig})$$

Here we use the fact that, for instance, $P(F \,and\, D)=P(F|D)P(D)$, so we really need

$$P(F) = P(F|D)P(D) + P(F|J)P(J) + P(F|P)P(P)$$

and these are all probabilities you can find using the hints above.

Hope that helps get you started!